# Wired communication of Raspberry Pi 3 Model B to Pi Zero

Tags: spi

I am trying to make a personal robotic assistant, and i am using 2 Pi Zero's to control 2 main parts of the robot, the assistant's voice and voice recognition systems, and the facial recognition systems, which i would like to work together, so i am attempting to connect them to the raspberry pi 3 as like the "brain."

Basically, is there any way to control a pi 0 with a raspberry pi?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you researched Robot Operating System ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can program in Go, Node.js, or Ruby, then you might want to look at [GoBot.io](http://gobot.io).

GoBot is a lightweight framework that has several communication frameworks and Raspberry Pi is one of them. I have my Linux laptop speaking to a Raspberry Pi Zero W, just to see if I could do this. My next experiment will be to have wired communication.

If you look on the front page, they have "sister projects" written in Ruby and Node.js.

The Go code runs on a larger computer (PC, Raspberry Pi, that sort of thing) and through and "adapter" (a communications protocol) they communicate with microcontrollers if necessary. The same technology allows for communication between multiple Raspberry Pis.

It is a much lighter framework than ROS, though, but it is much easier to learn.

Comment: It looks like GoBot is ideal for Arduino/Pi MCU's slaved off a single PI MCU master linked via USB using serial communications. For a peer-to-peer relationship, good old REST/node works for loose collaboration over larger distances via internet.

Comment: They do use a Restful API to talk between the Raspberry Pi's. You'd use a different protocol to be able to talk between Raspberry Pi's. i'd assume Firmenta, and as soon as I can set up two Pi's, I'll test this.